# Is it possible to disable edge reversal for cycles in elkjs layered graphs?

Tags: eclipse-elk

I'm using ElkJS to draw graphs in a dialogue system for game development. I'm currently using layered graphs and would like to disable the cycle breaking feature that reverses edges.

Does anybody know if this is possible?